# problem with SSD

Tags: laptop, ssd

Decided to put an additional SSD, to put back the system itself, but my computer does not see the SSD, through the BIOS can not see anything to, tell me what could be the problem?
laptop: acer aspire 3750
PS: 
Prisches apologize for my bad English

Answer (score 0):

This sounds very much like a hardware problem.  Even a brand new, never partitioned SSD should show in BIOS and partitioning software if it's correctly connected.  Open up the machine and check the SATA cable connections and make sure the SSD power connector is plugged in; if that fails, try plugging the SSD into a different SATA connector on the motherboard.  One of those will most likely correct the issue for you.